# What intellisense dropdown is this, and how do I turn it off?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, intellisense

I'm having some problems with Visual Studio and Intellisense - whenever I click <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Space</kbd> to get the regular intellisense dropdown, I get the one shown in the picture instead.

Which setting should I change to prevent this behavior?

[How do I get the regular intellisense? http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/8737/vsdropdown.png](http://img121.imageshack.us/img121/8737/vsdropdown.png)

*This happens in all sorts of files, not just xml...*

This problem has appeared since I installed some extensions - I believe this is related either to the Visual Studio Pro Power Tools extension or R#, but I'd rather solve it without uninstalling either of them.

Comment: It is from R#. I don't know what it's for or how to disable it individually though.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Those look like [live templates](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/features/codeTemplate.html) from ReSharper. You might be able to turn them off by going to `ReSharper -> Live Templates -> Predefined Templates` and unchecking the items you do not want.

From your screen shot, the `a` template is under the *XML* node, the `ctx` and `nguid` are under the *<no language>* node.

Comment: I ended up disabling all of them, since I don't use them anyway. Haven't seen the tooltip since =)